# php session timeout in loop?

Tags: php, session, loops

How do I do a loop - while the session is authorized check if the time has expired.  My code looks like this:

```
while ($_SESSION['auth']) {
    $inactive = 600;
    if (isset($_SESSION['timeout'])) {
        $session_life = time() - $_SESSION['timeout'];
        if ($session_life > $inactive) {
            session_destroy();
            header("Location: logoutpage.php");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? What is the end result you want to achieve? Is this for some kind of long-polling or what?

Comment: Tell us the scenario; what are you trying to achieve? Because this, with lots of visitors, and provided this would even work, could quickly become a resource hog for your server, me thinks.

Comment: Hi I am busy with a testing site, the user only has for example 1 hour to complete the test so the script constantly has to check if the time has expired and if it has throw the user out.

Answer (score 0):

Wow **do not** do that you will get stuck in a loop for a while..

But all in all, the loop you have now should work.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the prompt reply.  I'm not sure I understand?  Is my code correct, because it doesn't work? What should I not do?  Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've done the following, maybe it can help someone else:

**page1**

```
session_start();
///
$teststart = 3600;
$now = time();
$testend = ($now + $teststart);
define(testend1,$testend);
$_SESSION['now2'] = $now;
$_SESSION['testend2'] = testend1;
header('Location:http://localhost/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=51');
```

**page2**

in the head section so that the page refreshes

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">
```

then in page 2

```
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['auth']) {
$session_testend3 = $_SESSION['testend2'];
$now = time();
if ($now > $session_testend3) {
session_destroy();
header('Location: http://localhost/');
  exit;
}
}else{
echo "you are not authorized";
}
```